# ReactJS: Reload a new instance of the component?

Tags: reactjs

I hope I am capable to explain my question in a understandable way.

I am very new to React! And I am not familiar with how some things get done yet.

I have a `GamePage` component. On this page I am rendering a `GameRound` component.

When the game starts, a new "game round" starts. After the game round has finished, I want a second and then a third game round to start. This means I need to get kind of a "new" `GameRound`. The `GamePage` should remain.

While writing this, I got an idea of how this could be achieved: In my `gameRoundFinished()` event, I could reset the state of the GameRound. But is that already the most elegant and especially the Reactive way doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Some code as requested...

**GamePage.js**

```
export class GamePage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Set game configuration and data
        this.state = {
            gameId: props.match.params.gameId,
            settings: {
                categories: ['Stadt', 'Land', 'Fluss'],
                countdown: 5
            },
            activePlayers: {},
            game: null
        };

        // Open socket
        this.socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3000');

        this.socket.emit('join', this.state.gameId);

        this.socket.on('updatePlayers', players => {
            this.state.activePlayers = players;
            this.setState(this.state);
        });

        this.socket.on('startGame', () => {
            this.state.game = {
                rounds: []
            };
            this.state.game.rounds.push({

            });
            this.setState(this.state);
        });
    }

    onClick = () => {
        this.socket.emit('ready');
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.game) {
            return (
                <GameRound socket={this.socket} config={this.state}></GameRound>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div>Currently {this.state.activePlayers.length}/3
                <Button onClick={this.onClick}>klick</Button></div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**GameRound.js**

```
export class GameRound extends React.Component {
    // too much code that is irrelevant for the question

    render() {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide some code in your question so that others can more easily understand how your app looks and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to "reset" a component (and re-run the constructor) is to use the `key` prop.
See https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key

In your case: be sure to provide a new key at every round change: something like:

```
<GameRound key={roundId} socket={this.socket} config={this.state}></GameRound>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before other things it is necessary to clean the code:

To call functions together with synthetic events in the render method:

```
<Button onClick={this.onClickEvent()}>click</Button></div>
```

To use `this.setState({ a: 123 })` for changing `this.state` object, but not to use `this.state` itself for changing the state.

Good example:

```
this.setState({ activePlayers: players });
```

Bad examples

```
this.setState(this.state);
this.state.game = { rounds: [] };
this.state.game.rounds.push({ ... });
```

You may want to use `socket.on()` function to change your state as follows:

```
socket.on(){
  ...
  this.setState({ activePlayers: players });
}

<Button onClick={this.socket.on()}>click</Button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to design `GameRound` so that it accepts props to determine its behavior. Then to "reset", you just pass the appropriate values for the props to set it to the new round.